# Performance tests

Tags: java, performance

How to make performance tests on Java? Such as time of execution, a track of using memory, a track of operations per second and may be there are another helpful tests. How to realize this tests without an influence to the real application work (without this test)? I mean that I could be confident that my application would be work with the same performance on average without those tests.

**Note: I need to attach a specific tool to my test class. I know that there is many different tools to test a huge amount of VM parameters of an application. I need to write a test class with distinct test parameters which values I can handle as I want. It would be good if API supported graphical GUI for some those parameters.**

Comment: you can use professional tools such as jprofiler and jprobe.

Comment: Having 15 years experience performance testing systems, its not something you can get a short description to.  The reason is that you can perform simple tests but these give you no idea what the performance will be like in a real system.

Comment: I would suggest using a profiler when you find that you have a performance problem.

Comment: you can try http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/ for time benchmarking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tools like jconsole, visual vm especially for the memory. These come bundled with the Jdk.
 As for the speed of your application, typically log messages can help you with that. If the log messages follow a standard you can pretty much write your own script to give you a pretty formatted result. Also, it is a good idea to write test classes to give you a fair idea of the performance for varying loads.

http://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html

Comment: I watched in Google what is jConsole and I found that is a distinct tool. But you suggest to write a test class and this is my main goal. What is the package or class to do it?

Comment: JUnit and TestNG are my favorites to write tests. However, you can also explore http://clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html. Maybe we can help you with an example if we knew the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend jProfile for performance test and jConsole for Monitoring memory usage etc...

Comment: JProfiler is a commercially licensed Java profiling tool. Is there a free tool?

Comment: @itun - here is a list of the most popular ones.  http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers

Answer (score 0):

I am under the assumption that your servers are hosted on the linux env. Jconsole and Visualvm are indeed helpful to monitor your memory and performance. Just as a work around you can also use sar, top and mpstat commands to get your required values. 
You will have to install the sar package on your linux server by command sudo apt-get install sysstat. You can refer "http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/?utm_source=feedburner" to learn more on the commnads.
You don't need admin access to configure any of these commnds..